# Cache, Database, Over 400k Listing

Tags: mysql, caching

In my MySQL database I have a table of products which contains almost 625k rows. The table has 162 columns.

Now there is a search box on my home page where you can search for anything and, if your search term is matched from any of my product titles, it give you a list of 15 products. This is similar to Amazon and other e-commerce websites.

What I did so far was to create a JSON file with all the product ID's and title names. When user inputs a minimum of 3 chars into the search field, an AJAX request is made and gets the list. But my issue is that the JSON file is almost 12MB in size, and the ajax calls it whenever user write's a char or removes a char. It was working fine until I was on local Machine and now as soon as I made it live it doesn't work for users, having lower then 5 MBPS internet connection. So I am looking for some advice, how do I create it fast as Amazon. I mean the search with auto suggestion from 625K products.

Comment: Please post examples of what you have already, but it sounds like you have a issue surrounding caching (or a lack thereof). In this case I'd suggest that you look to implement something in this respect. Or, at the very least, a view seeing as you probably don't search all 162 columns.

Comment: I have the json file as object of arrays and on user input i just get the result from that json and filter it as string match, but it's not the best solution. and what I want to implement is how amazon auto suggestions works, I want to implement the same exact thing.

Comment: Your database structure is wrong. What you are doing with JSON is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am really sorry, but there is nothing more to give as an advice here then "go do some reading on database design and schema normalization".

If you have 162 columns in a table you will never be able to do an efficient search. The database (especially MySQL) will not hold the table in memory and indexes will not help either. Yes, you can throw it all into an ElasticSearch instance and it will fix some of your problems. But, honestly, this solution does not clean up the mess you have.

You should have a table with relevant information (titles, names, etc.) in one column (or also a numeric column for prices, etc). This metadata should reference the main table, the column should be fulltext-indexed. This way you ask for matches, filter results and `JOIN` relevant lines from the main table. This will work quickly with very little resources used.